# Fix the upstream dependency conflict in Angular

Tags: angular, npm-install, ngx-international-phone-number

I know the answer to this question is already available on SOF but I can't use --legacy-peer-deps or --force on my production server that's why I want to learn the real reason behind why this error occurs and want to fix it.

On installing some libraries I am getting the following error, does anyone know how to resolve it without forcing it? I am working on Angular 14, If need be I can downgrade too.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because your dependency `ngx-intl-tel-input@3.2.0` is depending on an `@angular/common` version between 8 - 13. But your app is on angular 14 with `@angular/common@14.0.7`.

You have two options:

1. If possible, upgrade `ngx-intl-tel-input` to a newer version, that makes use of `@angular/common@14.x.x`
2. Downgrade your app to angular 13.

**Edit**
You've added a second image. Here it seems you are just missing `@angular/animations`. Try `npm i @angular/animations`

Comment: Can you check the 2nd image I have attached and tell what version mat-timepicker requires?

Comment: I downgraded my angular to 12 and it already had "@angular/animations": "~12.0.5", and the error remains but as I understand it requires angular/amination v14 which again won't work for the first case so I am kinda stuck again lol

Comment: Can you add your package.json to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in angular 14, so I tried this library ***[ngx-mat-intl-tel-input](https://npm.io/package/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input)*** and it worked for me

Comment: can you share a bit more of how you used it? for me it creates an invisible box and the country dropdown in the left of the screen https://prnt.sc/RPAR-Cm308l2